# Integrate Exotel COD App with Magento

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, magento-community, application

I m trying to integrate exotel COD app with my magento website which sends a confirmation to the customer when the order is placed. In order to integrate this app it requires a URL which returns http 200 when a order is made successfully or some other code when it fails. I wanted to ask whether magento does something like this on the backend? or how to i write a new script for this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a module which implements an observer and listens for the [events triggered when an order is placed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927618/magento-observer-for-order-state-is-complete). You could then send your response like that.

I don't know if this is the best way but it's what came to mind.